# 2 classes which implements the same interface

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I am wondering if it is a good practice in dependency injection to have 2 classes which implements the same interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
    String get_message();
}
    
public class Test1: ITest
{
    public String get_message() { return "I am Test1";  }
}

public class Test2 : ITest
{
    public String get_message() { return "I am Test2"; }
}
```

In ConfigureServices() method (Startup.cs): I have add:

```
    services.AddTransient<ITest, Test1>();
    services.AddTransient<ITest, Test2>();
```

My question is: How can i differentiate Test1 and Test2 when i want to access to Test1/Test2 class by dependency injection

Thanks

Comment: This all depends and what it is you are actually trying to do. What is the scenario?

Comment: In fact i want to understand why DI Configuration should by like this: services.AddTransient<ITest, Test1>(); and not services.AddTransient<Test1>(); or services.AddTransient<ITest>(); I want to understand why we are allowed to configure 2 classes with the same interface in DI

Comment: Because you can inject them as a collection `ctor(IEnumerable<ITest> args)` and get all registered types.

Comment: The class(class1 or class2) which you try to access or instantiate through constructor, will be of type you get. I think, this should work like we try to convert.